how to set cdsapi on CDS climate data store of ECMWF?
I am facing problem to update my cdsapi to use new beta version of climate data store of ECMWF.
i need assistance on the exact syntax of new cds api
is this is the correct syntax:
url: https://cds-beta.climate.copernicus.eu/api
key: 470039e9-26b0-4a06-9fb6-43d5c12a98dc:6593e3ce-ac5c-49ca-ad4a-c329d8859c0f
